# Solution distribution in a quadratic congruence

Tags: nt.number-theory, congruences

Fix a modulus $M$. For varying $m$, consider the (possibly empty) set $R_{m,M}$ of roots of $x^2\equiv m^2+2 \pmod{M}$.

Are there good known bounds on
$$\sum_{m\le M^{1/100}}\sum_{r\in R_{m,M}}\min(M^{1/100},{1\over\|r/M\|})$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the distance to the nearest integer?

I would hope for a bound of $\ll M^{2/100-\delta}$ for some explicit $\delta>0$.

Comment: I assume $r$ is chosen to lie between zero and $M-1$.